# Get Wordpress login functions without printing anything

Tags: login, api

I want to serve a dynamically-generated PDF with a "File Transfer" header

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
```

However, before I generate the document I need to verify the user's login and credentials.

```
if(is_user_logged_in()){
     $currentUser = wp_get_current_user();
     $userLogin = $currentUser->user_login;
     if(userAllowedAccess($requestID, $userLogin)){
         header('Content-Description: File Transfer') 
         ....... file content
     }
     else{
         //Do nothing... get off my lawn
     }
```

}

Where do I put this so I don't get any headers or output from my wordpress page?  I need to load enough of the API to get my is_user_logged_in() and wp_get_current_user() function but don't want to load anything that prints to the page...

Suggestions?

Thanks-
J

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean the [`Content-Disposition`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266) header.

I recently did a very similar thing for a client.  My weapon of choice: custom rewrite rules.

First, add the rewrite:

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'wpse27232_add_rewrite' );
/**
 * Adds the rewrite rule for the download.
 * 
 * @uses add_rewrite_rule
 */
function wpse27232_add_rewrite()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^download/?$',
        'index.php?file_download=true',
        'top'
    );
}
```

When someone visits `yoursite.com/download` they will catch this rewrite. Notice the `index.php?file_download=true` bit.  WordPress has no clue that `file_download` should be a recognized query variable.  So let's make that recognizable by filtering `query_vars`.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse27232_query_vars' );
/**
 * Filter our query vars so WordPress recognizes 'file_download'
 */
function wpse27232_query_vars( $vars )
{
    $vars[] = 'file_download';
    return $vars;
}
```

Now the fun part: catch the `file_download` query variable and send the file.

```
<?php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse27232_catch_file_dl' );
/**
 * Catches when the file_download query variable is present.  Sends the content
 * header, the file, and then exits.
 */
function wpse27232_catch_file_dl()
{
    // No query var?  bail.
    if( ! get_query_var( 'file_download' ) ) return;
    
    // change this, obviously. Should be a path to the pdf file
    // I wrote this as a plugin, hence `plugin_dir_path`
    $f = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'your-file.pdf';
    if( file_exists( $f ) && is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        // Do your additional checks and setup here
        
        // Send the headers
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename( $f ) );
        header( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize($f));
        // You may want to make sure the content buffer is clear here

        // read the pdf output
        readfile($f);
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->is_404 = true;
    }
}
```

Finally to get this little [plugin](https://gist.github.com/2316232) to work, an activation hook to flush the rewrite rules.

```
<?php
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpse27232_activation' );
function wpse27232_activation()
{
    wpse27232_add_rewrite();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches to do such:

- page template
- Ajax action
- custom handler that loads core
- early hook (such as `template_redirect`)
- and so on...

Personally I'd go with Ajax action. It's pretty clean way to get full environment without any output and not overly complex to implement. See [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) in Codex.